# Linux останавливается после начала загрузки

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, xubuntu

Прошу помощи

При загрузке Linux в Grub я выбираю мою Linux систему, идет загрузка а потом останавливается на этом моменте
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше система не загружается

спасибо

Comment: Жмите Alt+F2, логиньтесь и читайте логи, где что сломалось

Comment: вот тут достаточно толково написано https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418992/sgx-disabled-by-bios-message-on-ubuntu-20-04-booting